# How to add the private framework in iphone os to our app?

Tags: iphone

HI ,,

Is there any to add the private framework in our app which is not released by apple ?

Can we use all the private framework by any way aur we have any restriction to dump that framework ?
After using that framework apple accept our app or not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have private frameworks in an iPhone app if you want to sell it through iTunes.

Comment: i actually don't know how to fix that really other wise i do that 

can u pls help regarding this

Comment: To accept an answer for a question, simply click on the empty checkmark to the left of the appropriate answer.